# How to debug TFS online Build, Could not find file?

Tags: asp.net, tfs, tfsbuild

I'm trying to build a solution on TFS online Build, the solution build successfully on all team members machines without any pre configuration, but unfortunately it's fail to build on "tfs online build".

the error message from tfs build console:

```
##[error]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(2603,5): Error : Copying file bin\MainConfiguration.config to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\MainConfiguration.config failed. Could not find file 'bin\MainConfiguration.config'.
```

[image]
i have a MainConfiguration.config file inside the core project and AfterBuild event in Admin.API to copy the config file from core project to /bin folder in Admin.API project and every think is working perfectly in team members machine

```
 <Target Name="MainConfigurationIntegration_config_AfterBuild" AfterTargets="AfterBuild" Condition="Exists('..\Core\Config\MainConfiguration.$(Configuration).config')">
<Copy SourceFiles="..\Core\Config\MainConfiguration.$(Configuration).config" DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)" />
<Move SourceFiles="$(OutputPath)MainConfiguration.$(Configuration).config" DestinationFiles="$(OutputPath)MainConfiguration.config" />
```

i'm not sure if this the issue or in some place else, where and how to start debugging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was that msBuild on tfs online try to copy the file `bin\MainConfiguration.config` to `obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\MainConfiguration.config`
before copy it to `bin\MainConfiguration.config` so i have edited the copy target action and make it run before the build process to be like:

```
  <Target Name="MainConfigurationIntegration_config_AfterBuild" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild" Condition="Exists('..\Core\Config\MainConfiguration.$(Configuration).config')">
    <Copy SourceFiles="..\Core\Config\MainConfiguration.$(Configuration).config" DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)" />
    <Move SourceFiles="$(OutputPath)MainConfiguration.$(Configuration).config" DestinationFiles="$(OutputPath)MainConfiguration.config" />
  </Target>
```

and it works

Answer (score 2):

> How to debug TFS online Build, Could not find file?

According to the error:

> Error : Copying file `bin\MainConfiguration.config` to
>   **`obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\MainConfiguration.config failed`**.
>   Could not find file 'bin\MainConfiguration.config'.

It seems that you are publishing a Web project as a package when this error occurs.

So, to debug this issue, first, we need make sure the custom target is executed successfully, that means the `MainConfiguration.$(Configuration).config` is copied from `core` project and rename it to `MainConfiguration.config`.

You could add tasks [Copy Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) task and [Publish Build Artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops) task in the build pipeline to output the build directory, so that we could check if that `MainConfiguration.$(Configuration).config` is copied successfully.

Then you should make sure build and publish task in the **same** agent job, otherwise, the build and publish task may run on different agents, your custom target will fail.

Since we do not have more information, like the build definition about get source, build task, publish task, we could not give you accurate problem location, if above info could not help you resolve this issue, please share more info about it.

Hope this helps.